# How Close PrimeFaces PhotoCam?

Tags: image, jsf

I'm using photocam for take picture with camera but capture option is always open. I am using photocam autostarts property with created to button which invite a method like that:

```
    public void pcFotoStarter() 
{
        if (pcFoto == Boolean.FALSE)
            pcFoto = Boolean.TRUE;
        else
            pcFoto = Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

This method makes my method's pcFoto field true or false , and then I defined `<f:ajax execute="button" render="PhotoCam" />`

According to the pcFoto Boolean Value(true or false), photocam is working or not. Problem is, photocam starts at once and I can close only 1 time photocam.Ant than I am unable to restart photocam. And my webcam usage yellow led is flashing. It's like webcam is already in usage.

Comment: hi guys ... any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

try execute this Javascript code when you want to off camera

```
Webcam.stream.getTracks().forEach(x=> x.stop());
```

In my case i turn on camera while open p:photoCam in p:dialog (dynamic) and has p:ajax  callback on "close" event. Like this

```
   <p:dialog id="modalDialog" widgetVar="photoEditDialog"
              modal="true" onHide="PF('photoEditDialog').toggleMaximize();"
              resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true"
              dynamic="true"
    >
      <p:ajax event="close" update="photo @this" onsuccess="Webcam.stream.getTracks().forEach(x=> x.stop());"/>
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <section>
          <h1>Camera</h1>
           <p:photoCam widgetVar="photoCam" listener="#{cc.attrs.value.onPhotoCapture}" update="preview"
                            width="400" height="300" photoWidth="1024" photoHeight="768"
            />
              <p:commandButton type="button" value="Capture" onclick="PF('photoCam').capture()"/>
        </section>
         <section>
           <h1>Preview</h1>
           <p:graphicImage id="preview" value="#{cc.attrs.value.photo}" stream="false"/>
        </section>
      </div>
    </p:dialog>
```